# Error in compiling Delphi mobile application for AppStore configuration

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I compile my application for ios simulator and Android (with delphi xe5), every thing is OK, but when I compile my application for Appstore configuration I get this error, I googled the error but I didn't find anything helpful.

> The required attribute "Include" is missing from element
>   . 
>   E:\Users\RezaRa\AppData\Roaming\Embarcadero\BDS\12.0\iPhoneOS6.1.sdk

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution, I removed the SDK from tools->option->SDK Manager and added it again, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when compiling for macOS.
My solution is to click on the button "Reset path to default ..."

You can find it in:

Tools- Options - Delpoyment - SDK MANAGER and select the appropriate SDK. 
On the right side there is a button with a red dot.